# Why does a swimmer cross a swimming pool in the same time as crossing a flowing river?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, velocity

I read that the time taken to cross a swimming pool (still waters) is the same minimum time required to cross a flowing river, provided the swimmer crosses it the river in the minimum time required, and the pool and the river are of the same width.

My thinking is:

- In the pool, the whole component of the swimmer's velocity is forward, so time taken would be $\frac{W}{V}$ where $W$ is the pool width and $V$ the velocity.
- When crossing the river, time taken would be $\frac{W}{V_y}$ where $V_y$ is the component of the swimmer's velocity perpendicular to the width of the river, assuming the river flows along the x-direction. Hence time to cross the river would be more.

Why is this wrong?

Comment: In practice, river surface is much less flat than pool surface (and there could be "big" waves from boats), so breathing is harder (requires more effort) in the river. In the pool that extra effort is redirected to propulsion. Also, waves add resistance? Also, in practice, open-water swimming technique is slightly different: you rise your head more, from time to time, to look for obstacles and for wayfinding, which is less efficient. But let's forget about all that. :-)

Comment: As a way to help visualize it, let's say that in both scenarios, we put a camera on a floating buoy right behind the swimmer. The buoy flows along the river, and remains stationary in the pool. If you look at the camera footage, how would it be different, barring the moving scenery which has no bearing on the swimmer in the water? (Hint: there is no difference between the two movies)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Your reasoning would be correct *if* the swimmer in the river was trying to reach the point on the bank opposite where they started. To do this they have to swim in a direction angled upstream, so relative to the water they have to swim a longer distance than the width of the river.

But to cross the river in the *minimum time* the swimmer should swim in a direction perpendicular to the banks. The river will carry them some distance downstream, but they will only have to swim the width of the river relative to the water  - which is the reference frame in which their swimming speed is measured. So although they travel further *relative to the banks* it only takes them the same time as swimming across a swimming pool of the same width.

Comment: This will give the minimum time, but not by as much as you might think. I wish I had time to run a rough calculation of the case of a swimmer heading diagonally upstream so as to travel straight across - the current provides a sideways force on the angled body.  This is known in kayaking as a ferry glide, from the [chain ferries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_ferry) that use only this force for propulsion, held against the current using a fixed cable.  Even better would be to do the experiment, but opportunities for that are rather limited

Comment: @ChrisH, Re, "...chain ferries...force...held against the current..." None of which helps a swimmer who is floating freely in the water. Nor does it help a kayaker *unless* there is a standing wave on the river that the kayaker can surf across. (Note: I personally have crossed flowing rivers in kayaks, with and without surfable waves, more times than I can possibly remember.)

Comment: If it helps, you can visualize the river as being stationary, and the *banks* as moving in the opposite direction. Then it's clear that crossing this stationary river takes the same time as crossing a swimming pool.

Comment: @Solomon the mention of the chain ferry was little more than etymology. Of course as a swimmer or kayaker you're working against the current. As a kayaker (like me) you'll understand ferry gliding as well as I do; of course finding a perfectly even flow and suitable banks is unlikely. I wonder if I can reduce it to a force diagram that's simple enough to solve while still being realistic enough.

Comment: @ChrisH this is a idealized physics problem from the get go. so it is assumed that the bank is climbable everywhere and the river is straight and even for the stretch the swimmer drifts down

Comment: @ratchetfreak yes, a big logic gap between my 2 sentences: the one about finding a river meant taking my real swimming gear (or kayak) to real water.  The one about a force diagram didn't.  For a start you'd probably assume the swimmer was a flat plate, and that the banks don't contribute appreciable edge-effects.  But my fluid dynamics is so rusty I'd be starting from scratch.

Comment: One reason I said in my first comment "not by as much as you think" is that considering vectors forming a (thin, i.e. low-current in this case) right triangle, the hypotenuse isn't much longer than the next longest side. Even if the current and the swim speed are equal, it will only take a factor of √2 longer to go straight across by swimming at 45° to the flow than to go 45° downstream by straight across.  In the real world I don't like to swim against currents where I can't hold my own though I've been in a few rivers recently (kayaking is a different matter of course, at least whitewater)

Comment: @ChrisH I don't think we can assume low-current. Rivers easily flow as fast as swimmers swim, or even faster. Trying to swim straight across can easily take a much longer time, or even be completely impossible. Your example is also not correct: if current and swim speed are equal, the swimmer needs all his speed to stay at the same place, and has none left to make progress towards the other bank.

Comment: @RoelSchroeven good spot - I'd equated the wrong two speeds.  I'm well aware of rivers flowing faster than I can swim, or paddle.  They're a hazard, fun, or both, and I try to avoid swimming in them except when safety training for whitewater kayaking, etc.  For the purposes of this problem, they're also rather boring, which is why I chose to assume a slow current.  I'd say that may be implied in the question too

Comment: @ChrisH Your comment about reaction ferries got me thinking, and I'll go one step more and say under some conditions [the river can be crossed _faster_ than the swimming pool.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/665803/24140)

Comment: @ChrisH Did you notice that √2 is about 1.44?  Swimming 44% longer is quite a lot. This 45 degree angle is not an upper bound. The faster the river and the slower you swim, the more additional distance you have to cover.  Imagine the river flows at 2 m/s, and you are able to sustain a 2.1 m/s swim. You will pretty much be swimming straight upstream with a slow skewing motion toward the other bank. The total distance might be many times more than the width.

Comment: @Kaz, true, but as I said above, I was assuming a fairly low current (less than or equal to swim speed) for a more interesting problem.  If the river is much faster than you can swim, you're trivially going to end up a long way downstream whatever you do.  Also if angled even slightly across, so the upstream component  of the swim speed is equal to the current, you'll get a cross-river force from the current itself.  The magnitude depends on the shape (the lift/drag ratio), but this propels you across even if all your effort is spent upstream, so long as you're angled right

Comment: @printf Except, of course, that the "stationary river" case has a wind blowing.  The swimmer need only extend their sail to exploit that!  ;)

Answer (score 8):

As gandalf61 has explained, one way to view this problem is the current flow could be considered orthogonal to the intended direction of travel. With such a view, the minimum crossing time solution is to swim directly perpendicular to the current, while allowing the current to sweep you downriver.

But I will make what is sure to be a contentious claim: this isn't actually the fastest way to swim across a river, and in fact a river with current can be crossed in *less* time than a swimming pool of the same width, given some leeway with the definition of "swimming" and some generosity regarding the feasibility of the idea.

What you say? How is this possible?!

Here's another physics question: say there is a sailing course on open water with a start and a finish, the finish being directly downwind of the start. At the starting gun, a ballon is released to drift freely in the wind. Can a sailboat, powered by nothing but the wind, make it to the finish before the balloon?

The answer is, counterintuitively, yes. The reason is that the sailboat can generate *lift*, effectively extracting energy from the wind which the balloon can not. The fastest path for the sailboat is not to sail directly downwind, but actually at some angle away from it, and then to turn periodically, taking a zig-zag path towards the finish.

In fact, very cleverly this technique can be used to construct a vehicle which can travel downwind *faster* than the wind by turning the sails into a propeller. Such a vehicle is demonstrated in this [Veritasium video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyQwgBAaBag). Compare the direction of the windsock to the streamer on the vehicle and you can see that the vehicle is in fact traveling faster than the wind.

[image]

Now how does this apply to swimming across a river? [In a comment, Chris H referenced reaction ferries](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/665487/why-does-a-swimmer-cross-a-swimming-pool-in-the-same-time-as-crossing-a-flowing#comment1492410_665490) which use a fixed tether to cross a river. Their propulsion comes not from any power source, but rather by accelerating the river current towards the bank using the rudder, and the reaction force propels the ferry.

This got me thinking, is there any way a swimmer could use the river current to generate lift? If so, it's possible crossing a river could be faster than a swimming pool of the same width. I can imagine there could be many possible techniques, and I'll not claim any of them are feasible, only that they are theoretically possible. Demonstrating feasibility will have to be left to a better swimmer than I.

Here's one such technique: consider that a person simply floating in the river, not swimming, is equivalent to a person floating in a swimming pool with a breeze. We know that sailboats could cross a swimming pool with a breeze, and so a swimmer, if allowed to carry a sail, could extract some propulsive force from the apparent wind through a similar mechanism. If this propulsive force can be attained in addition to the force from ordinary swimming, doing both (swimming and sailing) at the same time will result in crossing the river faster than the swimming pool.

If the swimmer is not allowed a sail, I think we can still not rule out the possibility that the swimmer's own body could not be oriented in such a way as to achieve a similar aerodynamic advantage. I'm somewhat skeptical of the feasibility of this approach, since I'd guess the aerodynamic advantages would be more than offset by the disadvantages of a less effective swimming technique, but at the same time I can't think of a theoretical reason it's not possible.

If that's too far-reached, here's another idea: a swimmer can certainly use the same reactive force that propels reaction ferries, but only until they have been accelerated to match speed with the current. A reaction ferry uses a tether to prevent this from occurring, and a swimmer has no such tether, but that does not mean the current is useless, only that it is only temporarily useful. I would think with sufficient practice it should be possible to extract a little bit of lift in the first few seconds after diving into the river, gaining some initial advantage on the swimming pool swimmer. After the dive, the river swimmer would swim perpendicular to the current as before, but that initial advantage would mean the river swimmer would arrive first.

Comment: Interesting ideas. I started thinking about lift/drag ratios just using the current, and got rather too far into forces on a body in a fluid flow. One easy trick would be to push off or even dive heading upstream, to carry some upstream momentum. The former effectively redefines the start point, so seems like too much like cheating; in the latter case I think it's fair to assume banks like the sides of a swimming pool, so you can only push off perpendicular to the edge or nearly

Answer (score 1):

In first approximation, namely when considering the river a medium with constant linear speed, that is a reasonable assumption.  But the flow speed of rivers is not constant: it is higher in the middle than at the banks.  That causes additional drag and Bernoulli forces on a body depending on its shape, orientation, and movement.

It is not uncommon for people to drown in a large river and be found dozens of miles downstream.  A river that would move as a block would be quite easier to exit and would have people wash up at the first slight bend.

So the counterintuitive result from simple physical considerations actually has problems matching reality once we are talking about water that moves at large enough speed.